# On a question of finite extension of a prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and $F$ a finite field with $p$ elements, let $K=F(\xi)$ be a finite extension of $F$ such that $[K:F]=n$.
Then $\mathcal{G}=\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)=\langle \sigma\rangle$ where $\sigma(k)=k^p$ for all $k\in K$.

**Question: Is it possible that $\xi\xi^{p^m}=\xi^{p^i}$ for some $1\leq m\leq n-1$ and $1\leq i\leq n-1$?**

Here, I intend to understand the conjugacy class
$$\{\sigma^j(\xi)\mid 0\leq j\leq n-1\}=\{\xi^{p^j}\mid 0\leq j\leq n-1 \}.$$
I would like to know is it possible that there are two elements in this class such that their product is still in this class.

I learned my knowledge of field theory from abstract algebra course and I knew little about trace and norm. Any explanation, references suggestion and examples are appreicated.

Comment: What does the notation $k^\sigma$ mean? I saw that notation for fixed fields already, but not for elements.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I'd guess it means $\sigma(k)$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes, that makes sense considering it's the Frobenius homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, $k^\sigma$ means $\sigma(k)$.

Comment: Is there an extra $\xi$ in there? "$\xi\xi^{p^m}$"?  Note that $\xi\neq 0$, so you can cancel it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  No, there is no extra $\xi$ in $\xi \xi^{p^m}$. Here, I intend to understand the set $\{\xi^{p^j}\mid 0\leq j\leq n-1 \}$. I would like to know is it possible that there are two elements in this set such that their product is still in this set.

Comment: You exclude $m=0$ which is just as well as in characteristic $2$ we'll always get $\xi\xi=\xi^2$: but I do wonder if that's the only way that can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In the cases I see, $\xi$ needs to be a root of unity of a low order. But there may be other kinds of examples also.

---

The first example I thought of is when $\xi$ is a fifth root of unity, and $\Bbb{F}_2(\xi)=\Bbb{F}_{16}.$ The conjugates of $\xi$ are then (iterating Frobenius):
$$\xi^2,\ \xi^4,\ \xi^8=\xi^3,\ \text{and back to}\ \xi^{16}=\xi.$$
You see that all the non-neutral elements of $\langle\xi\rangle$ form a set of (Galois) conjugates, so there will be plenty of examples.

---

More generally, the same thing happens whenever $\ell$ and $p$ are prime numbers such that the residue class of $p$ generates the group $\Bbb{Z}_\ell^*$. If $\xi$ is a root of unity of order $\ell$ in an extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$, then its conjugates, $\xi^{p^i}$, $i\in\Bbb{N}$, are again the non-trivial elements of the multiplicative subgroup $\langle\xi\rangle\simeq C_\ell$. In other words, the number of conjugates of $\xi$ is equal to $\ell-1$ and $\Bbb{F}_p(\xi)=\Bbb{F}_{p^{\ell-1}}$.

The first example is an instance of this as the residue class of $p=2$ generates all of $\Bbb{Z}_\ell^*$ when $\ell=5$.

---

Such $(\ell,p)$ pairs are utilized in efficient computer implementations of large finite fields. Particularly in the crypto implementations of $\Bbb{F}_{2^{\ell-1}}$ when $p=2$. This is because the conjugates of $\xi$ then form what is known as *an optimal normal basis*. That is, a normal basis with as simple a multiplication table as possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for your very clear explanation. Inspired by your explanation, I found an example when $\xi$ is a root of unity of composite order: $\xi$ is a primitive $9$-th root of unity, and $\mathbb{F}_5(\xi)=\mathbb{F}_{5^6}$. Then $\xi\xi^{5^4}=\xi \xi^4=\xi^5$ and $\xi\xi^{5^2}=\xi \xi^7=\xi^8=\xi^{5^3}$. It seems that if we require $\{\sigma^{j}(\xi)\mid 0\leq j\leq n-1\}\cup \{ 1\}$ to be a group, then $\xi$ is a root of unity of order $\ell$ which is a prime such that the residue class of $p$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}^*$. @Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: That's a nice example, @user44312. When the conjugates form a "dense" subset of a multiplicative group, examples are likely to appear!

Comment: Thank you. @Jyrki Lahtonen. What do you mean by saying "dense" subset of a multiplicative group? Could you explain it?

Comment: Like in your example, when the residue class of five generates $\Bbb{Z}_9^*$, and consequently the Galois conjugates of $\xi$ cover two thirds of the elements of the group $\langle \xi\rangle=\mu_9$. That two thirds is a largish fraction (which is what I meant with "dense"). I suspect that we can find many examples in so called semiprimitive cases, where $\xi$ is a root of order $m$, and $p$ generates a subgroup of index two in $\Bbb{Z}_m^*$. For example when $m=45$, $\phi(m)=(3^2-3)(5-1)=24$ and $p=2$ has order $24/2=12$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{45}^*$.

Comment: (cont'd) Sure enough, if $\xi\in\Bbb{F}_{2^{12}}$ is a root of unity of order $45$, both $\xi^{16}$ and $\xi^{17}=\xi^{2^9}$ are among the Galois conjugates. Here $2^9\equiv17\pmod{45}$.

Comment: As the residue class of $2$ generates all of $\Bbb{Z}_{3^k}$ and all of $\Bbb{Z}_{5^m}$ for all $k,m>0$, it follows that $2$ generates a subgroup of index two in $\Bbb{Z}_{3^k\cdot 5^m}$, and it is likely that similar examples can be found in there for some choices of $(k,m)$.

Comment: I think you miss some *. But, I get your point. Thanks very much again for your detailed explanation. @Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: Oops, you are right. I wrote $\Bbb{Z}_r$ in place of $\Bbb{Z}_r^*$ on a number of spots. Well done spotting the error.